# 500 error on Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

this is my ajax code for an onclick of a button.  The alert box shows me the values are correct. But when it attempts to go to the controller it gives me a 500 error. The controller is ContentPackController.

```
$(function () {
        $('#updateContent').click(function () {
            var selectedValue = $('#contentAlias').val();
            var value = $('#contentPackDetails').val();
            alert(selectedValue + " " + value);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateContent", "ContentPack")',
                type: "POST",
                data: { PropId: selectedValue, UpdateText: 'Looking For An <span class="embellish">Great Deal</span> On Your Next Home?"' },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }, success: function () {
                    alert("Updates have been saved");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is the ActionResult that should be called

```
  public ActionResult UpdateContent(int PropId, string UpdateText)       
    {
        using (var entities = new OpenRoadEntities())
        {
            var prop = entities.ContentPackDetails.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id==PropId);
            prop.Value = UpdateText;
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new EmptyResult(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

This is just driving me crazy. Other calls to the same controller work correctly.

Comment: You're making a POST request and that action looks like it's set up for GET.

Comment: what does you apache error log say?

Comment: @PaulAbbott its not even hitting the action. It should still hit the function shouldnt it?

Comment: It won't hit your action because it is not decorated as `[HttpPost]`. By default (undecorated) it is `[HttpGet]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the HTML tags in your POST data.  MVC validates the data and throws an error if it detects potentially unsafe content.  Either come up with some sort of markup that gets converted in the action or add the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to your action.